# Samsung Kies mode.Current mode not supported on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, kies

When I try to connect my Samsung Galaxy S1 to a computer running Windows 7, the following incomprehensible messages appear:

[image: kies error message]

> Reconnect the device in Samsung Kies (PC Studio) mode.Current connection mode not supported by Kies.
>   Check the USB settings.
>   (Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging(x))

Can you help me? I tried everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your S1, is USB debugging ON ? ( *Settings->Developer Options->USB debugging* in case of ICS or *Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging* incase of earlier versions).
Try switching it off and then connecting the USB cable.

Comment: Thanks, It really helped, I was trying to set USB Debugging checked, why the message doesn't tell anything about UNCHECKING Usb Debugging?

Answer (score 0):

download this usb driver from samsung site,its working

http://www.samsung.com/ph/support/model/GT-I8262MBAXTC-downloads#

Answer (score -2):

Your PC needs a driver for Kies to recognize your phone.
Download & install Samsung-Usb-Driver-v1.5.45.0 or newer version.
After installing, open Kies, and your phone should be recognized.

Comment: This answer is very hard to understand. Can you expand upon it and tidy up the grammar and spelling?